# Wifi-Hardware seems not to be enabled

Tags: wifi, hardware

in my MSI Wind-Box DC 110 I have this Wifi Chip:
RTL8188CE
(says the sticker on the chassis and the vendor told me that they are sure the device is implemented)

and I cannot connect to any Wifi - still I don't see even the "Wireless Connections" Overview in the Network Dialog...

I am Using Ubuntu 12.04.

*I already changed the driver to the right version following this tutorial
http://unixblogger.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/the-pain-of-an-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-ethernet-card/
And the r8168 Driver is in use. (which was for the ethernet controller and had nothin todo with my problem :( )*

But no Wifi LED is shining and no Wifi connections are listed.

There is no hardware trigger on the device to enable or disable Wifi

What can I do? It seems that I cannot detect the device...

**UPDATE**

```
$: iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:c018 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 05ac:0221 Apple, Inc. Aluminum Keyboard (ISO)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. //a card reader
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0781:5571 SanDisk Corp. //a usb stick
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05ac:1006 Apple, Inc. Hub in Aluminum Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04e8:6881 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd //a mobile phone
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point Thermal Management Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

Comment: Realtek 8168 is not a wireless adapter: http://www.realtek.com.tw/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=12

Comment: If you have a PCI wireless card (should have an antenna sticking out in the back) run `lspci` and provide us with the output, or if you have a USB wireless dongle run `lsusb` and provide us with the output.

Comment: UPDATED MY QUESTION^^ , it seems that I actually cannot detect the device. it shell be an RTL8188CE chip (says the sticker on the chassis)

Comment: Can you post the output of `lspci`? That would show if the card is present but needs a driver.

Comment: It seems RTL8188CE doesn't have a driver in Ubuntu 12. This Q/A at askubnutu has the link to the driver to download: http://askubuntu.com/questions/260991/rtl8188ce-wifi-adapter-is-not-detected-after-installing-newest-realtek-driver

Comment: well I already tried that... check out update as well

Comment: I also tried to install those compat drivers for rtlwifi ...http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Linux_Wireless

Comment: Not seeing the device in `lspci` list. Either the card is not seated properly, or the hardware has failed. I would start diagnosing the card by moving it to another machine. If that machine doesn't pick it up either then you are probably looking at a dead card.

Comment: damn! :D I will get my screwdriver tomorrow and have a look inside that baby